# How to find all the zeros of a cubic spline?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, zeroes, splines

Let's say I have a cubic spline represented piecewise by cubic polynomials. Do you know an efficient algorithm for computing all its zeros?

Thank you.

Comment: You can find some useful tips here:   

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/280148